# Presenting a UIViewController with a custom size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, popupwindow, window-resize

I've been beating my head against the wall on this for a while.  I have an iPad app that uses the Master-Detail SplitViewController as its presentation framework.  I need to present a login dialog when the app first loads, and have it be of a custom size.  I've created a UIViewController scene in the main storyboard, and load the VC when the DetailController first loads.

The problem I'm having is that I flat-out can't control the size of the VC.  I've got it defined as FormSheet, to be displayed in Portrait mode.  I set the Presentation to FormSheet. I try to explicitly set the size several different ways, but absolutely nothing works.

The fundamental issue is that because of all of this, the VC *always* presents in fullscreen as portrait.  And when I rotate to landscape, it *stays* in portrait mode, leaving gaps on the right and left and cutting the top and bottom of the view off.

This is incredibly frustrating and I really don't know where to go from here.  The interesting thing is that after the app fully loads, I present the exact same kind of VC using a tap.  It presents beautifully, using the following as the setup:

```
MyViewController *itemDetails;

itemDetails = [Globals.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

itemDetails.itemImage.image = imageView.image;
itemDetails.jewelryObject = jewelryObject;

itemDetails.delegate = self;

itemDetails.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
itemDetails.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemDetails];

itemDetails.navigationItem.title = jewelryObject.itemDescription;

[navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

navigationController.view.superview.autoresizingMask =
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
    itemDetails.view.superview.frame.origin.x,
    itemDetails.view.superview.frame.origin.y,
    540.0f,
    450.0f
    );
navigationController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;

self.itemDetails = itemDetails;
```

I'm so incredibly frustrated I can't even express it.  As much as I love programming for iOS, there are those occasional WTF moments that make me wish I were a hermit.  If anyone has any "ahah!" insights they can throw at me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you considered using a popover viewcontroller? It seems like it might be a good fit for this.

Comment: A popover would be a last-resort effort.  I'd basically have to make sure that no external taps are allowed, which is certainly feasible.

It's just amazing to me (as Matt Galloway indicates below) that there's no official way to do this.  But I kludged a similar solution together that works in another part of the app, so I just can't see why it's causing so many problems now.

I've tried to load the VC into the SplitViewController on first-load, but the VC doesn't even show up.

Unbelievably frustrating.  Thanks, though.  If I can't get a solution in place soon, I'll go with your idea.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so... This is not technically supported. There is no official way to present something at a certain size. So the real answer to this question is - file a [radar with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

But... It is possible. However if you don't understand the code below, then please don't use it. It goes like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

UIViewController *viewControllerToPresent = /* ... */;
viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

Ivar instanceVar = class_getInstanceVariable([UIViewController class], "_formSheetSize");
if (instanceVar) {
    ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(instanceVar);
    CGSize *offsetVCPtr = (CGSize*)(((uintptr_t)(__bridge void*)viewControllerToPresent) + offset);
    *offsetVCPtr = size;
}

// Present as usual with presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

It's ugly, but it works. Note that I don't particularly recommend doing this in an App Store app as you may not get through review with something like this in there. Use at your own risk! Remember the real answer to your question - it can't be done with the existing API.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  I've really had my wits tested today.

Thanks for the suggestion.  *Something's* got to give on this.

Comment: Oh, and this is not a for-public app.  It'll be released as an Enterprise app, so there'll be no official blessing bestowed by Apple.

Comment: Or the much simpler `[vc setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:size] forKey:@"formSheetSize"]`.

Comment: Yes indeed you could do that. The reason for the way I did it is for other reasons! But he's setting value for key is better.

Comment: Just as a follow-up, now that my brain has cooled down a bit--where did you guys find out about formSheetSize?  I've been googling a bit, and I can't find any references to it.  Can't find anything in the Apple docs, either.  Seems like the source for this nugget would be a good place to go for further education.

At the very least, is it safe to assume that the formSheetSize property is private?

Comment: It's not documented. I found out that there was an instance variable called that by inspecting the class at runtime. There's various bits of software that can do this for you, that can extract equivalent header files as if everything were exposed. Google for "iOS runtime headers" :-).

Comment: Heh.  Sweet.  I'll do that now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally figured out how to use UISplitViewController correctly, so all of this dancing around with customized VCs was for naught.  I call [UISplitViewController presentViewController:animated:completion] after all the basic structures are set up in the Detail Controller.

I was really screwing around for a while.  But it's working now, so ... Winning! ;-)

Thanks for all of your help.  I really do appreciate it.  You got my wheels turning, which is what I needed.  I'll play with your suggestions at some other point, just to satisfy my own curiosity and add another arrow to my quiver.

Thanks again!